# Speech to text with wave avatar

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

What I want to do is,with the help of unique characteristics of the individual or unique type of utterance of his/her email id ,I want to display a wave avatar unique to his/her voice .

Is there any libraries or Apis or projects already done using js? If yes please let me know (Though i have googled,i didn't find any).If there are none(references) for my help , what would be the best possible step that i should take? (I am new to speech processing but have some theoretical concepts on sound theory ) Any kinds of helps are highly appriciated.